# cvs to git conversion on Debian

Tags: git, debian, cvs

I just installed a VMWare image for Debian 6 to experiment with git.
Ultimately, I need to convert a CVS repo to Git.
I have installed git cvs package. 
When I type git-cvsimport, it does not find the command.
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: is that path to that file in your `PATH` variables? can you run it from whatever `/bin` it's in?

Comment: oops, never checked the obvious. I was convinced I did not have the correct package installed :( Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path was the issue... I never checked the obvious